# How to handle multiple inheritance of same methods or diamond problem with CRTP static polymorphism?

Tags: c++, crtp, diamond-problem, static-polymorphism

I want to implement polymorphism statically with CRTP. I want to create several base classes that provide functionalities. However the functionalities can be overlapping. However if they overlap, they are identical.

Suppose I have

```
template<class derived> class Boxer {
public:
    void walk(int nsteps) { 
        for (auto _ = nsteps; _--;)  static_cast<derived&>(*this).step(); 
    }
    void punch() { static_cast<derived&>(*this).moveArm(); }
protected:
    ~Boxer() = default;
};

template<class derived> class ChessPlayer {
public:
    void walk(int nsteps) { 
        for (auto _ = nsteps; _--;)  static_cast<derived&>(*this).step(); 
    }
    void playChess() { static_cast<derived&>(*this).think(); }
protected:
    ~ChessPlayer() = default;
};

class ChessBoxer : public Boxer<ChessBoxer>, public ChessPlayer<ChessBoxer> {
public:
    void step() { std::cout << "one step at a time \n"; }
    void moveArm() { std::cout << "moving my arm\n"; }
    void think() { std::cout << "thinking\n"; }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   
    ChessBoxer vec;
    vec.walk();
    vec.punch();
    vec.playChess();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Both `Boxer` and `Chess Player` provide `walk`. Both definition of `walk` are identical.

By the way, I could (and probably I should) rewrite the code above to avoid the duplication of `walk`'s code .

```
template<class derived, class top> class Walker {
public:
    void walk(int nsteps) {
        for (auto _ = nsteps; _--;)  static_cast<top&>(*this).step();
    }
protected:
    ~Walker() = default;
};

template<class derived> class Boxer : public Walker<Boxer<derived>, derived>  {
public:
    void punch() { static_cast<derived&>(*this).moveArm(); }
protected:
    ~Boxer() = default;
};

template<class derived> class ChessPlayer : public Walker<ChessPlayer<derived>, derived> {
public:
    void playChess() { static_cast<derived&>(*this).think(); }
protected:
    ~ChessPlayer() = default;
};

class ChessBoxer : public Boxer<ChessBoxer>, public ChessPlayer<ChessBoxer> {
public:
    void step() { std::cout << "one step at \n"; }
    void moveArm() { std::cout << "moving my arm\n"; }
    void think() { std::cout << "thinking\n"; }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   
    ChessBoxer vec;
    vec.walk(3);
    vec.punch();
    vec.playChess();
    
    return 0;
}
```

But still that creates the diamond problem.

How can I solve this problem, **keeping static polymorphism**? Also I want the final derived class to not have to bother with technicalities.

Comment: would a chessboxer walk as a chess player or as a boxer?

Comment: Sorry, I think that my question might have been a bit confusing. Boxer and chess player walk in the same way. More technically, let us just look at the second code block. That creates the diamond problem. With dynamic polymorphism, that problem is addressed by inheriting the base classes as virtual. However I cannot find how the diamond problem is solved for static polymorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. I do not take credit for the solution.

One possible solution can be found at the following webpage
https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/08/28/removing-duplicates-crtp-base-classes/
of Jonathan Boccara's blog.

Another solution is provided in Matthew Borkowski's comment within the same page, and it links to the code http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/463db3673b139429

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose how your character will walk: as a boxer or as a chess player. Once you make up your mind (say boxer) you can then add one line:

```cpp
class ChessBoxer : public Boxer<ChessBoxer>, public ChessPlayer<ChessBoxer> {
public:

    void walk(int nsteps ) { Boxer::walk(nsteps); } // this line

    void step() { std::cout << "one step at a time \n"; }
    void moveArm() { std::cout << "moving my arm\n"; }
    void think() { std::cout << "thinking\n"; }
};
```

Your `walk()` in main is wrong, I fixed it:

```cpp
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   
    ChessBoxer vec;
    vec.walk(3); // this
    vec.punch();
    vec.playChess();
    return 0;
}
```

The result is then

```
Program stdout

one step at a time 
one step at a time 
one step at a time 
moving my arm
thinking
```

[Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/cM3WEWEbx)

Comment: That defeats the very purpose of what I am trying to do. The base class should add functionality to the derived class, without requiring further implementation. What I want to do can be done with dynamic polymorphism by inheriting the base classes as virtual. However that does not work with static polymorphism. My question is, with dynamic polymorphism there is a way to solve the diamond problem, what is the way to solve it for static polymorphism implemented with CRPT?

Comment: But you have a decision to make. It's not even a matter of language. This would appear even with dynamic polymorphism (using virtual inheritance). See this example: https://godbolt.org/z/z3YPzhaKE

Comment: Thanks, but I think I can make it work with dynamic polymorphism. Please see: [godbolt.org/z/44MYMj94o](https://godbolt.org/z/44MYMj94o)